# Can I change close reason after I made a mistake?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just voted-to-close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420987/no-errors-but-not-able-to-run-app-in-swift). It is duplicated of something but I can't remember.

So I am searching it in the "Closing > Duplicate" window. I tried a few keywords but give me some not related question. Then I changed keywords and hit enter... and now it recorded me voted-to-close as a duplicate of something unrelated. I can't find a way to change it. What can I do now?

---

Update:

This question is now closed by a moderator. and now my incorrect duplicate-of question is appear on top of the question (above the correct one) and looks confusing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't change your close vote. But you can [retract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/165773) your close vote. If you do, you will be unable to vote to close the question again.

So if the vote is really that far off, retract your vote and then comment with the duplicate post. Then let the community do its thing.

Comment: Thanks. I will rescind my vote next time. But it is too late now...

Comment: @BryanChen I noticed that. You maybe able to flag it with a custom flag to have a mod reopen it, and then close it with the correct duplicate. But as a quick resolution in this case, I'd just comment on the question explaining the situation for OP.

Comment: @StevenV: "it's thing" -> "its thing", "you're duplicate" => "your duplicate" :)

Comment: Matthieu, if the rules around editing say that you shouldn't edit posts for small things like grammatical errors, then should we also not apply this to comments? I think we can take a lesson from Elsa on stuff like this. (For the parents of young daughters, I do apologize, because I know it's stuck in your head now. =( Very sorry.)

Comment: @corsiKa The grammar issues were in a comment that I deleted since the OP edit the contents of my comment into his post. Matthieu couldn't edit it, and I couldn't edit it either since it was outside the five minute window.

Comment: Lol - what I mean is ... who cares about trivial grammatical errors. I know the stories about lawsuits awarding large sums of cash because of an errant comma, but this isn't that. To the four people who upvoted a grammar nazi correction comment, shame on them. =\ Just my thoughts.

Comment: @corsiKa, but its quiet irritating when peoples posts have bad grammar and spelling in their. ;)

Comment: Why can't you change your close vote reason? What is the thought process behind that?