# Is this an appropriate use of the dupehammer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, dupehammer

I've been trying to help a user with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40261763/2675154). However, it became clear to me that the user hasn't gathered enough information to properly diagnose the issue.

On face value, my dupehammer vote is for an unrelated issue (how to debug a windows service), but it's really at the very core of what the user is asking, and the lack of information is inviting somewhat speculative answers.

Did I do the right thing?

Comment: I think I might've closed it as lacking MCVE, instead.

Comment: Yes you did ;-)

Comment: I'd agree with @Cerbrus because it was the lack of the try-catch code that lead to speculative answers, mine was no exception (pardon the pun).

Comment: To me this is up there with NullReferenceException type questions, where it's perfectly acceptable to close "unrelated" questions for the canonical answer.

Comment: One issue with closing as a dupe "just to get it closed" verses something else is dupes are not auto cleaned up the same way as non dupes are.  That means we could keep "garbage" around longer then normal.

Comment: "one cannot singlehandedly close a question as off topic. But a concerned person always trying to close a bad question as soon as possible, in order to discourage both rep-whores and help vampires. Luckily, almost every silly question is a duplicate, and thus can be closed in one click..." ([Understanding the community and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336777/839601))

Comment: @JoshCaswell did spender fail to include a MCVE? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting question wrongly closed as duplicate of how to debug reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307326)

Comment: I generally disagree with closing questions as dupes of the various "This is how to debug the problem yourself" questions / answers.  Yes, the OP would not have posed the question if he had been able to debug the problem himself, but the question is (ordinarily) *not* about how to debug, it is about what the nature of the bug *is*.  There may well be other good reasons to close or downvote, or there may even be a more fitting dupe, but that's a different matter.  It could be useful to ensure that the "how to debug" question is linked as related, but it is not a good dupe target.

Answer (score 7):

This is again the result of the the essential ambiguity of the Stack Overflow's nature.

*Each question is actually asked by more than single person:* one who literally posts it on SO *and many others who ask it on Google.*

For some reason, the community is strongly inclined to be servile towards the former one, eager to spot a typo in the posted code, or to even to unleash a live debug orgy in the comments. Leaving the poor folks coming from Google without a hint for *their* problem.

And it is quite interesting a phenomenon, given the declared goal of Stack Overflow: to be the source of all the knowledge in the world.

From this point of view, given folks coming from Google outnumber the silly OP, *and each with their distinct issue,*

#### The information on how to debug your problem is the only proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem if you use the dupe hammer this way, is that nobody learns from their mistakes. If the question should be closed because it is bad in some way, the OP needs to know the reason why so they get a chance to improve. Otherwise they'll do the same mistake again and again.

If the question lacks information, the correct way is to close vote as off topic -> "questions asking for debugging help-..."  That's probably what you should have done instead.

This particular question isn't horrible and could probably get salvaged if the OP could edit it to add more information. It doesn't seem like the post would necessarily turn out as a duplicate after edits, in case the OP has some problem that's unique to their specific case.

Comment: No, the OP needs to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @torazaburo What do you mean with that? Did you even read what I wrote?

Comment: I read your statement saying *the OP needs to know the reason why*. I was responding that "*No, the OP needs to learn how to use a debugger*.

Comment: @torazaburo And how exactly will they learn that from someone with a gold badge implicitly telling them "this question has been asked before", rather than explicitly telling them to post their debugging efforts?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's fine* to "abuse" the dupehammer in such cases: the question is unclear / too broad / off-topic because not enough information, so shouldn't be answered in the first place.

Then the duplicate and its answers explain in great detail how the asker can get unstuck and continue working on their problem without others having to spend effort at guessing what the actual problem is.

However, if you do this, I think you're obliged to keep following the question to notice if anyone is complaining in comments about the close-vote, and you should reopen in a jiffy if it turns out your question of choice was less than perfect or didn't explain the problem clear enough for the OP.

*: until "heavier-weighting close-votes" are implemented.

Comment: Dumb question: with the dupehammer can you insta reopen?

Comment: @Steven yes, if it was closed as duplicate, even if you closed it yourself.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, then it should be closed as a duplicate. If the question is not a duplicate, then it shouldn't be closed as one, ***NO MATTER WHAT!*** Otherwise, the close reasons have no actual meaning. Abuse of power is an abuse of power, whether it is done for good or ill.

Comment: @Nicol well I think it's a matter of interpretation. In cases of such questions as the one discussed here, or the ones about a NullReferenceException or ASP.NET 500 Internal Server Error pages, the implicit question that _I_ read is _"I don't know where to start with troubleshooting this issue"_. I think it's fine to then close as duplicate of a question that does show how to troubleshoot said issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Nobody ever asks *"How to use a step debugger?"* but it is
>   technically a fair duplicate target of every question that would never
>   have been asked or the answer is easily uncovered using a step
>   debugger.

There will always be the *every question is sacred, unique snowflake* crowd that thinks down voting much less closing question is mean and hateful, blah, blah, blah, I feel they can be safely and silently ignored as they are part of the problem.

Comment: Broad complaints (valid or invalid) about the general SO ethos isn't helpful in answering this specific question.

Comment: I have no problem with downvoting or closing questions, but I have serious concerns with closing a question as a dupe of one that is only tangentially related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing that "abusing" thing from time to time for several reasons and in special cases only:

- when the question is too broad or has no MCVE, not when unclear
- leaving it open for more than 1 minute will attract lousy/plagarized answers, and possibly upvotes on them
- closing them with the duplicate solves the OP problem
- because if you vote to close as too broad and OP edits his question, the question can really become a duplicate. Since you [cannot change close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261605/can-i-change-close-reason-after-i-made-a-mistake), you're stuck.

In other cases (typo, unclear, code dump why isn't this working), you should use non-duplicate close votes, always.

Note that:

- I usually comment/give a quick personalised solution for the OP, and explain why I linked to a duplicate
- I try to add more than 1 duplicate so there's more information for the OP
- I reopen when I'm pinged with a good reason to do so (not asked very often)

So far no-one complained, not OP, not high-rep users or mods. So this is something I'll keep on doing. Of course, if other close reasons had weighted votes for gold/silver badge users, maybe I'd have a tendency to avoid it.

If you want to see some "abuses" I perpetrated to see what I *really* mean, here they are (the recent ones, some may be deleted by now):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174812/program-to-find-palinrome-using-python
- [Opening a folder with multiple CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162155/opening-a-folder-with-multiple-csv-files)
- [Calculate sum of even numbers between 1 to 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152789/calculate-sum-of-even-numbers-between-1-to-101)
- [Python saving and loading variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141532/python-saving-and-loading-variables)
- [Python 3.6 class method argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126001/python-3-6-class-method-argument)

Answer (score -1):

Well, when all you have is a dupehammer, most questions start looking like duplicates.  Not that this is a bad thing, mind...

On the one hand, you've done a good thing; you've closed a question which isn't the best quality and is solved more by the user debugging their own code than having us debug it for them, which is in the best interests of all of us.  It stopped [more] uninformed answers or "best" guesses at solving this problem, which means there's less noise to filter through to get signal.

On the *other* hand, you've taken a privilege intended to do one thing - close questions as duplicates - and used it instead to close a question as "unclear what you're asking", or "why isn't this code working?"

While I'm okay with the result, I personally feel that it shouldn't have to come around like this, since someone who sees this later on might *disagree* with the dupe closing and attempt to apply a better close reason, which would largely undo the work that this particular closure did.

You pose the question of, "Did I do the right thing?"  In essence, an unclear question is now closed until the OP can hopefully get more details to prospective answerers to avoid any ambiguity.  However, you've had to use a tool that's very narrow in scope (and intentionally narrow in scope) to accomplish it.

**You did the right thing in the wrong way.**  I doubt I'd personally do it, but I don't want to see it reversed in this current state, either.

Comment: You are coming tantalizingly close to suggesting expansion of the dupe hammer to other reasons--why not go ahead and take the plunge?

Comment: @torazaburo:  I've already [made some suggestions to this effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270829/1079354) already, but not necessarily immediately concerning the venerable dupehammer.  I do feel like the community wants these expanded powers, and that these expanded powers can be helpful, but shoehorning them in with the dupehammer is anything *but* helpful.